# Creating new Unity launcher fails

Tags: unity, launcher

I've generated a `.desktop` file, a shortcut to a directory.
After clicking works fine, so the syntax should be correct.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Link
  Icon[pl_PL]=gnome-panel-launcher
  Name[pl_PL]=Projekty
  URL=/home/user/my/projects
  Name=Projekty
  Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

But when I drag it to the Unity launcher (says "Drop here to add a launcher")
nothing happens after dropping.

What do I miss?

Comment: I would suggest you pastebin.com your desktop file so that we can confirm the syntax.

Comment: @fossfreedom I've added the source

Comment: is that a copy/paste error? - why those two extra lines above the [Desktop Entry]?

Comment: @fossfreedom No, this is not an error, this is the source as generated. But removing those lines does not change anything, still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can tray the following:

1. create the .desktop **(projects.desktop)**
2. You can write this code

   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Projects
   Comment=Access and organize files
   Exec=nautilus /home/user/projects
   Icon=system-file-manager
   Terminal=false
   NoDisplay=true
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
   Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
   Name[en_US]=projects
3. drag and drop the file to the unity launcher.
4. The code is like the **nautilus-home.desktop** file in /usr/share/applications/ folder.
   You can change it acording to your needs.

Hope it will be useful to you!

Regards.

Roman